# rxgraph is not refreshed properly when a publisher shuts down

Tags: ros, rxgraph, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rxgraph is not refreshed properly when a publisher shuts down but the node handle stays alive. More exactly, the arrow in the graph stays, but the list of topics (in the right pane) is updated properly.

To reproduce, create a node with a publisher, create another node with a subscriber, observe the connection in rxgraph, then call shutdown on the publisher while leaving the node running, and finally observe that the two nodes are still shown as connected.

Is this a bug, or does it have an intended behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50271/rxgraph-is-not-refreshed-properly-when-a-publisher-shuts-down/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's probably a bug in the node deregistration.  I suggest filing a ticket on https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/new

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-03**:
When filing a bug, be sure to note if Python, C++ or both types of nodes have problems, and which version of ROS you're using.